# Shortest path property and monadic second order logic

Tags: lo.logic, shortest-path

I know that induced paths and Hamiltonian cycles can be expressed with monadic second-order logic ($MS_2$).

Is it possible to express the shortest path in $MS_2$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you want a formula $\varphi(s,t,X)$ in $MSO_2$ on graphs, stating that the set $X$ is the shortest path from $s$ to $t$. Under this meaning of "express the shortest path", no such formula exists.

We can prove this using the fact that there is no MSO formula that, given a word of the form $a^nb^m$, accepts it if $n\leq m$. This last fact is because MSO on words can only define regular languages.

For this, we can use a result of Courcelle and Engelfriet stating that if $\tau$ is a MSO interpretation $\mathcal C\to \mathcal D$ where $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal D$ are classes of structures, and if $L\subseteq \mathcal D$ is MSO-definable, then $\tau^{-1}(L)\subseteq \mathcal C$ is MSO-definable as well. See the book of Courcelle and Engelfriet for details on MSO interpretations and the proof of this theorem [here](https://www.labri.fr/perso/courcell/Book/TheBook.pdf) (there might be more recent and readable accounts).

Here, we can take for $\mathcal D$ the set of finite graphs where elements are nodes and edges (to capture $MSO_2$) with two distinguished points $s,t$ and a monadic predicate $X$, and for $\mathcal C$ the set of finite words.

The MSO interpretation $\tau$ will associate to each word a set of graphs (actually one graph or none) by defining the elements and relations as follows:

- if the word is not of the form $a^nb^m$ reject
- the nodes of the graph correspond to the positions of the word
- define $s$ to be the last $a$, and $t$ to be the last $b$
- edges are the same as in the word (two consecutive letters are linked), + an extra edge linking the beginning of the word to the end.
- the predicate $X$ marks $a$ positions + links between them and the extra edge.

We end up with a cycle, such that $X$ is the shortest path from $s$ to $t$ if and only $n\leq m$. This means that if there was a formula $\varphi(s,t,X)$ checking that $X$ is the shortest path from $s$ to $t$, we could obtain a MSO formula $\psi$ on words for $\tau^{-1}(L(\varphi))=\{a^nb^m\mid n\leq m\}$. So $\psi$ would be a MSO formula for a non-regular language, contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't understand the predicate X. Can you explain more about the predicate X?

Comment: @fva a structure equipped with a predicate $X$ means that a subset of the elements are marked as belonging to $X$, and that we can use membership to $X$ in formulas. We can for instance write a formula $\forall y,\exists z, E(y,z)\wedge z\in X$, meaning that every node is connected to a node in $X$. If you have a formula $\varphi(s,t,X)$ with free variables $s,t,X$ that you want to evaluate to true or false, you need in a structure where elements $s,t$ and a set $X$ are part of the signature. $\mathcal D$ here will be these kind of structures.